# Intellisense not working in VS 2012

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, visual-studio-2012

I downloaded a working MVC project to learn the actual MVC coding. On direct build, it gave me errors, I searched the net and as per suggestions I updated all the nuget packages and the other updates available. Now Razor is updated to 3.0, MVC to 5.2.3.0, Visual Studio to its latest version of VS 2012, and there is no intellisense anywhere on my project. I tried updating the web config with various values as suggested by users. I also tried updating the GUID. I created a fresh MVC 4 project and tried multiple times, but ended up updating the files and eventually back to Step 1. Its a hair pulling story now, as i cannot manage to get intellisense and all my work is stalled. Please help

Comment: Close your solution and reopen, or better yet, restart VS. Then rebuild.

Comment: @EdSF: I tried this many times, but to no avail. It just won't show intellisense.

Answer (score 0):

This might do the trick for you

```
Tools->Options->Text Editor->C# (or All Languages)->General
```

[image: Tools->Options]
[image: Text Editor]

and enable `Auto List Members` and `Parameter Information` in right hand side pane.

[image: C# (or All Languages)->General->Auto List Members and Parameter Information]

Comment: All of this is set. I can see intellisense when i create a new MVC application or any other project. Only this project is the one in which it does not work.